# Simple algorithm Hermite Normal Form for 3x3

Tags: matrices, algorithms, real-numbers

In the scope of the implementation of a model, I need to reduce a 3x3 real matrix into its Hermite Normal Form.

I am very new to this kind of reduction and only find algorithm using complex notions to perform this reduction.

Does anyone knows a simple algorithm to do this 3x3 matrix transformation ?

#### EDIT

Here are the algorithm I am refering to:
http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/pernet/Papers/Hermite/KannanBachem79.pdf,
[http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~havas/TR0295.pdf](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/%7Ehavas/TR0295.pdf) and
Havas et al., Extended GCD and Hermite Normal Form Algorithms via Lattice Basis Reduction

These algorithms call some notions such as determinent of non square matrix and other complicated stuffs (from my point of view). In general, these are for general nxn matrices with the aim to be the more efficient computationally speaking and I am looking for a simple way to do it for a 3x3.

#### SOLUTION FOUND

For the simple case of a triangular **3x3** matrix, we can take each line modulo the next line. At the end, apply the same operation to the first line with the last one.
This works for me and was what I was looking for. Sorry for the bad problem formulation and thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Which algorithm have you found too complex? We cannot find a simple(r) algorithm if we don't know the reference level

Comment: [link](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/pernet/Papers/Hermite/KannanBachem79.pdf) or [link](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~havas/TR0295.pdf) or [link](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10586458.1998.10504362#.UyMZr_HMGVB)

Comment: My point was rather that this should be part of your question (and you should also explain why you find them too complex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Just to remove from unanswered list]

For the simple case of a triangular 3x3 matrix, we can take each line modulo the next line. At the end, apply the same operation to the first line with the last one. This works for me and was what I was looking for. Sorry for the bad problem formulation and thanks for your inputs.